# Eclipse error in using a library

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

Hey guys i have a problem in reffering a library on eclipse.  Dont know if adding or referring but here maybe the picture will explain it.

[image]

Well this is the library i am trying to use, it is andengine which i download from github. But everytime i add  a library on my sample project click apply then close it. The opening it again to check f it is realy applied and has the green check it. But it shows this.

[image]

What is the problem here? it shows the x mark even though my project and the library are in the same workspace. Please help. Anyone know how to fix this? thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding the project to the workspace make sure that you check the box 'copy into workspace'

Comment: hmmmm ok guest i need to reimport my projects again

Comment: yes, go ahead and remove it from your workspace and simply import it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your workspace(with the project) and the library, must be in the same partition.

In your case, I imagine that should be both in D:\